# Combine Array and a Nested Array in React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui

I wanted to combine the parent array and its child array in one table.
The child array should have background color of green.

I have a difficulty doing it?

Please check my codesandbox
[CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/combine-array-and-string-in-mapping-in-react-forked-qmdd2q?file=/demo.js)

```
<TableBody>
      {[rows, rows?.personnels]
        .filter(Array.isArray)
        .flat()
        .map((row) => (
          <TableRow
            key={row.name}
            sx={{ "&:last-child td, &:last-child th": { border: 0 } }}
          >
            <TableCell>{row.fname}</TableCell>
            <StyledTableCell align="right">{row.mname}</StyledTableCell>
          </TableRow>
        ))}
    </TableBody>
```

**Expected Output**
[image]

Comment: The existing code-sandbox is applying `green` background to all cells in `Mname` column. Do you need both `child` elements to be background `green` and all `Mname` column elements to also have background `green`?

Comment: @jsN00b. Only Fname and Mname of Robert Williams and James Quincy to have a background of green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an array which flattens your rows and their childrens too into single array. And add conditional fname and mname render for both cases handling in TableRow.

```
import * as React from "react";
import Table from "@mui/material/Table";
import TableBody from "@mui/material/TableBody";
import TableCell, { tableCellClasses } from "@mui/material/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@mui/material/TableContainer";
import TableHead from "@mui/material/TableHead";
import TableRow from "@mui/material/TableRow";
import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";

const StyledTableCell = styled(TableCell)(({ theme }) => ({
  [`&.${tableCellClasses.head}`]: {
    backgroundColor: "lightgreen"
  },
  [`&.${tableCellClasses.body}`]: {
    backgroundColor: "lightgreen"
  }
}));

const rows = [
  {
    id: "111",
    fname: "Thomas",
    mname: "James",
    personnels: [
      {
        id: 1234,
        person_id: "233",
        parent_id: "111",
        person: {
          id: "233",
          fname: "Robert",
          mname: "Williams"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: "222",
    fname: "Jane",
    mname: "Doe",
    personnels: [
      {
        id: 4567,
        person_id: "333",
        parent_id: "222",
        person: {
          id: "333",
          fname: "James",
          mname: "Quincy"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
];

export default function BasicTable() {
  const arr=[...rows,...rows.map((e)=>e.personnels).flat()];
  console.log(arr)
  return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table sx={{ minWidth: 650 }} aria-label="simple table">
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell>Fname</TableCell>
            <TableCell>Mname</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
        {arr.map((row) => (
              <TableRow
                key={row?.fname || row?.person?.fname}
                sx={{ "&:last-child td, &:last-child th": { border: 0 } }}
              >
              {row?.fname ? (
            <TableCell>{row?.fname}</TableCell>
          ) : (
            <StyledTableCell>{row?.person?.fname}</StyledTableCell>
          )}
                {row?.mname ? (
            <TableCell align="right">{row?.mname}</TableCell>
          ) : (
            <StyledTableCell align="right">
              {row?.person?.mname}
            </StyledTableCell>
          )}
              </TableRow>
            ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
}
```

Code sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/combine-array-and-string-in-mapping-in-react-forked-dnq0zc?file=/demo.js:36-2278

[image]

Comment: I don't see Robert Williams and James Quincy in the table

Comment: Please open codesandbox link which I have attached its perfectly working

Comment: Robert Williams
James Quincy 
should all be background green, their Fname and Mname.
the others should not be green

Comment: Now check sandbox again.

Comment: There's still background of green on James and Doe?

Comment: I have updated the code too in answer. Please check it

Comment: Ok check it again

Comment: This is good but there might be more efficient approach

Comment: Actually you are flattening all objects in array and we have 2 cases for objects:
One for Person fname and mname and
Second for row fname and mname
So if we want to handle 2 cases in single logic and render then I think this is solution that we can do only.

Comment: Probably its better if we can create two arrays and separate them already before rendering?

Comment: You can use two arrays but the logic will be same as for arr1 you will render:
{arr.map((row) => (
              <TableRow
                key={row?.fname }
                sx={{ "&:last-child td, &:last-child th": { border: 0 } }}
              >
            <TableCell>{row?.fname}</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">{row?.mname}</TableCell>
              </TableRow>  ))}

Comment: For arr2:
{arr2.map((row) => (
              <TableRow
                key={row?.person?.fname}
                sx={{ "&:last-child td, &:last-child th": { border: 0 } }}            
             <StyledTableCell>{row?.person?.fname}</StyledTableCell>
              <StyledTableCell align="right">
              {row?.person?.mname}
            </StyledTableCell>
              </TableRow> ))}